# Validate Email Existence

Tags: php, email

I am trying to use [the "PHP SMTP Email Validation" library](http://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/)

On [line 163 of `smtp_validateEmail.class.php`](http://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/source/browse/trunk/smtp_validateEmail.class.php#163) the `$reply` variable is empty.

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone gotten this to work? Is there another library I should use?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell from the way you wrote your question what's going wrong. There can be numerous reasons and you did not provide much information about your problem. It can even be the case that the same problem will happen with any other library as well, so no recommendation can be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that you're not passing the `$email` variable to the function that creates the `$user` and `$domain` variables.

The function is `_parseEmail` and is defined on line 78

Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 2):

Not many mail servers are going to allow this sort of validation - it's far far far too easy for spammers to utterly nail a server with verification requests and build a list of valid emails they can flood with penis-pill-pushing-russian-brides-who-sell-PHDs spam.

If you're just trying to determine if an email address has a valid format, not that it actually exists, you can use

```
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to determine if an email is valid and exists, then send an email to it. If you've forced the user to enter in their email twice, there is really not much more you can do other than send them an authentication email and that's it.